# How to convert a React Fragment to an Array?

Tags: reactjs

I am using an external library, Carousel, which expects its children to be composed of an array of react Components passed to it, i.e.:

```
<Carousel>
  <Component1/>
  <Component2/>
  <Component3/>
</Carousel>
```

I am also using a component, which returns a react fragment, filled with Components that I would like to pass to that Carousel Component.
**The solution that I had in mind is to convert that fragment to an array. Is there a way to do that ?**

for example, I want to turn this

```
<>
    <Component1/>
    <Component2/>
    <Component3/>
</>
```

to this

```
[<Component1/>, <Component2/>, <Component3/>]
```

then, all is left is to run map() on the input.

Comment: Fragment are not real markdown, it should work if you pass it in a fragment to the carousel

Comment: Which Carousel library is this?

Comment: @AjeetShah     "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.12",

Comment: @Zerowiel as a fragment, the carousel looked on all the components as a single element, compromising the very purpose of the carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cursory experimentation led to me finding that you can use `fragment.props.children`, which can then be mapped. See the following super-basic example:

```
export default function App() {
  const myFragment = <>
     <span>1</span><span>2</span>
  </>;

  return (
    <div>
      {myFragment}
      {myFragment.props.children
          .map(i => <div style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>{i}</div>)
      }
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems like a great answer/place to start... OP question is deceptively tricky, and I was going to comment that a potential *and very hacky* way to do it would be to assign a key to the fragment, then access it by way of `this._internalReactFiber.key`. Which, again, is *not* a terribly good idea/something I'd do in, say, an interview coding question.

Answer (score 0):

you can just return it like an array, what I have here:

my Component.js:

```
function Component() {
  return [<div>1</div>, <div>2</div>, <div>3</div>];
}

export default Component;
```

my App.js

```
import Component from './Component'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and it printed 3 divs with 1 2 3 on the screen, as expected

Comment: this causes the carousel to look on all 3 divs as one and it doesn't work correctly, arrows are not displayed, etc.